# pairwise comparison oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, comparison

Is there in a possible way to write these queries in one single query:

```
select code from carp.site where CODE_ADAM='038547' and CODE_IMPLANTATION='ND038547' and CODE_POSTAL='73479';
select code from carp.site where CODE_ADAM='034587' and CODE_IMPLANTATION='ND034587' and CODE_POSTAL='01994';
select code from carp.site where CODE_ADAM='037929' and CODE_IMPLANTATION='ND037929' and CODE_POSTAL='27367';
select code from carp.site where CODE_ADAM='038596' and CODE_IMPLANTATION='ND038596' and CODE_POSTAL='45721';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `OR` or `IN`:

```
select code
from carp.site
where (CODE_ADAM, CODE_IMPLANTATION, CODE_POSTAL) IN
         (('038547', 'ND038547', '73479'), 
          ('ND034587', '01994', '037929'),
          . . .
      );
```